# airflow PythonOperator watch zookeeper

Tags: python, airflow

Who knows how to use the airflow to watch a zookeeper path, when zookeeper path data is ‘success’, Change the state of task to success；when zookeeper path data is ‘fail’, Change the state of task to fail；
I write the following code，the ‘status_task’ task is used to get zookeeper status。 When I released the code to the airflow，but in the loop_func function ,  The code behind “while true” did not execute。 ‘status_task’ task status is always running。 Who knows why？

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from datetime import timedelta
import time
import requests
import json
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from kazoo.client import KazooClient
from pendulum import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.local_timezone()

zk_host = '172.23.5.85:2181,172.23.6.243,172.23.6.244'
global path
path = "/python/task1"


zk = KazooClient(hosts=zk_host)
zk.start()

args = {
    'owner': 'hadoop',
    'start_date': days_ago(2).replace(tzinfo=local_tz),
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='recipe_2',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=30),
    tags=['datatransform']
)

def http_get(ds, **kwargs) :
    print ("http_get ds:", ds)
    print ("http_get kwargs:", kwargs)
    url = kwargs["params"]["url"]
    print ("url:", url)
    r = requests.get(url)

    resInfo = json.loads(r.text)
    print(resInfo)

trigger_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='trigger_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=http_get,
    params={"url": "http://172.23.6.244:8830/getDataSet?id=1"},
    dag=dag,
)



def loop_func(ds, **kwargs) :
    global flag
    flag = True
    print ('first flag :', flag)
    print ("loop_func ds:", ds)
    print ("loop_func kwargs:", kwargs)
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        children = zk.get(path, watch=watch_func)
        print ('children : ', children)
        print ('flag :', flag)
        if (flag):
            print ("run count : ", i)
            i = i + 1
            if(1>100) :
                print ("task fail with run count :", i)
                break
        else:
            print ("task success !!!")
            break

def watch_func(event):
    print ('event', event)
    print ('event', event[2].decode('utf-8'))
    data = zk.get(event[2])
    print ('data : ', data)
    if("success" == data) :
        global flag
        flag = False
        return

status_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='status_task',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=loop_func,
    dag=dag,
)

trigger_task >> status_task

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

logs:

```
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,469] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: recipe_2.status_task 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,484] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: recipe_2.status_task 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,485] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,485] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,485] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,494] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): status_task> on 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,497] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 72250 to run task
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,586] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: recipe_2.status_task 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00 [running]> sz-pg-indexservice-funnel-001.tendcloud.com
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,608] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ('loop_func ds:', u'2020-05-18')
[2020-05-21 17:40:31,609] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ('loop_func kwargs:', {'next_execution_date': <Pendulum [2020-05-19T16:00:00+00:00]>, 'dag_run': <DagRun recipe_2 @ 2020-05-18 16:00:00+00:00: scheduled__2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00, externally triggered: False>, 'tomorrow_ds_nodash': u'20200519', 'run_id': 'scheduled__2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00', 'test_mode': False, 'prev_execution_date': <Pendulum [2020-05-17T16:00:00+00:00]>, 'inlets': [], 'conf': <airflow.configuration.AirflowConfigParser object at 0x7f25f3a436d0>, 'tables': None, 'task_instance_key_str': 'recipe_2__status_task__20200518', 'END_DATE': u'2020-05-18', 'prev_execution_date_success': <Proxy at 0x7f25ebe24dd0 with factory <function <lambda> at 0x7f25ebe0df50>>, 'ts_nodash_with_tz': '20200518T160000+0000', 'execution_date': <Pendulum [2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00]>, 'ts': '2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00', 'macros': <module 'airflow.macros' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/airflow/macros/__init__.pyc'>, 'params': {}, 'ti': <TaskInstance: recipe_2.status_task 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00 [running]>, 'var': {'json': None, 'value': None}, 'prev_start_date_success': <Proxy at 0x7f25ebe247a0 with factory <function <lambda> at 0x7f25ebe36aa0>>, 'ds_nodash': u'20200518', 'dag': <DAG: recipe_2>, 'end_date': u'2020-05-18', 'templates_dict': None, 'outlets': [], 'next_ds': '2020-05-19', 'next_ds_nodash': '20200519', 'task_instance': <TaskInstance: recipe_2.status_task 2020-05-18T16:00:00+00:00 [running]>, 'yesterday_ds_nodash': u'20200517', 'task': <Task(PythonOperator): status_task>, 'latest_date': u'2020-05-18', 'yesterday_ds': u'2020-05-17', 'ts_nodash': u'20200518T160000', 'prev_ds': '2020-05-17', 'tomorrow_ds': u'2020-05-19', 'prev_ds_nodash': '20200517'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought but have you considered making use of the [HttpSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/http_sensor/index.html)? It will poll for a given response and mark the task as success once that response is returned, and then your follow up task *trigger_task* can start.

Here's an *untested* example, to hopefully help you.

You'll need to create a new connection(HTTP) either through the Airflow UI or by setting an environment variable like:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_HTTP_ZOOKEEPER: http://172.23.5.85:2181
```

Then, the code would be like:

```
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.http_sensor import HttpSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'start_date': days_ago(1)
}
dag = DAG('http_sensor_dag', schedule_interval='00 * * * *', default_args=default_args)

wait_for_zookeeper_task = HttpSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_zookeeper',
    http_conn_id='http_zookeeper',
    method='GET',
    endpoint='/python/task1',
    response_check=lambda response: "success" in response.text,
    dag=dag
)

trigger_task= PythonOperator(...)

wait_for_zookeeper_task >> trigger_task
```

Comment: thank you very much。I know how to solve this problem。